# Adobe Acrobat Pro create PDF from web page javascript events not working

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I created a web page where sections of the page show/hides upon the value coming from select box. The HTML works fine when run in a browser, but it doesn't works when I create a PDF out of this html page using Adobe Acrobat Pro. The Javascript seems working looks it doesn't capture the events. Here is my code. Appreciate your help with this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <br/>
        <div id="section01_1">
            <select id="selector01">
                <option value="NA">Show a section</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="section01_2">
Enter Name:         <input type="text"
                   id="fname"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="section01">
        This is my section one
        </div>
                <div id="section02">
        This is my section two
        </div>
                <div id="section03">
        This is my section three
        </div>
                <div id="section04">
        This is always visible
        </div>
    </body>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        const el = document.getElementById('selector01');
        const box01 = document.getElementById('section01');
        const box02 = document.getElementById('section02');
        const box03 = document.getElementById('section03');

        box01.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        box02.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        box03.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        el.addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) {
        if (event.target.value === 'A') {
        box01.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
        box01.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        if (event.target.value === 'B') {
        box02.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
        box02.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        if (event.target.value === 'C') {
        box03.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
        box03.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I see it is not bringng in DIV elements at all. Any idea or alternative? I need a container I can show/hide based on value in select box.